# ACCESS 2016 - How can I stop the screen from jumping when page is switched after clicking on the tab

Tags: ms-access

In the OnChange event of TabCtl, I have the first field set to setfocus...field1.setfocus and have Field1.TabIndex is set to 0.

The probelm that occurs is: when I click the tab to change to another page, a field at the bottom gets the focus first, then field1 gets the focus.

This causes the screen to jump down, then up. I can watch the scroll bar scroll down, then up when the new page is displayed. How can I stop this behavior? 
Thanks in advance.

Additional Info:
Access is setting the focus to the last added field on the page
(which is at the bottom of the page off the screen),
For some reason it receives the focus before the vba setfocus is called
in the onchange event of tabctl.
If I add a new unbound field to to top of the page,
it gets the focus on page change and the jumping stops.
That may be the work around that I use...

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was adding Application.Echo False before my code runs, then Application.Echo True after my code is finished, so the screen is turned off until code has executed, then turned back on.